# How do I assign a value, to a 2D array location in C?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

So I'm quite a newbie, so please go soft.

I have created a 2D array, 60x30 and want to display it on the screen as a grid, by doing a double for loop. I am using a simple character '.' for each slot of the grid just for a test.

```
char FrameBuffer[29][59];
for (int i = 0; i <= 29; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 59; j++)
    {
        FrameBuffer[i, j] = '.';
        printf("%c ", FrameBuffer[i,j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

However, whenever I try and assign a value to a position in my 2D array, e.g.

```
FrameBuffer[0,1] = '.',
```

I am greeted with an error:

```
Expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

Comment: `<`, or declare `[30][60]`. Index 29 is out of bounds for array with dimension of `29`

Comment: `FrameBuffer[i,j]` --> `FrameBuffer[i][j]` (C and Pascal syntax differ here)

Comment: Typo one..... FrameBuffer [I][j] and use 0 to I <59

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FrameBuffer[29][59]` This is a 29x59 array, you need a 30x60.

Please don't mix up *array declarations* with *array indexing*. Array declarations are fully sane; if you need 30x60 then you type `FrameBuffer[30][60]`. When you access the array however, you start at index 0.

Simply change the code to:

```
char FrameBuffer[30][60];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++)
  {
    FrameBuffer[i][j] = '.'; // note the correct syntax here
```

---

EDIT

As a curious side-effect, `FrameBuffer[i, j]` is interpreted as something entirely different than intended. The comma here is regarded as the *comma operator*, a special kind of operator which evaluates the left expression `i`, then the right expression `j`, then returns `j`.

Meaning that the code ended up completely equivalent to `FrameBuffer[j] = '.'`. Where `FrameBuffer[j]` is a whole array, not a `char`. You can't assign a value to an array this way, an array is not a "lvalue", which explains the compiler error text.

Answer (score 1):

> FrameBuffer[i,j] = '.';
>
> printf("%c ", FrameBuffer[i,j]);

modify these two statements to

```
FrameBuffer[i][j] = '.';

printf("%c ", FrameBuffer[i][j]);
```

`[i,j]` means nothing to the compiler. It's nothing but an invalid syntax.

also correct you array.

`FrameBuffer[29][59]`it is an array of `row=29` and `col=59`

change it to `FrameBuffer[60][30];`

Comment: i am not that of an expert.